# Which web hosting is supporting website written by crystal language?

Tags: web, web-hosting, web-development-server, crystal-lang

I am newbie in Crystal lang and start to use web development. Which web hosting is supporting website written by crystal language?

Answer (score 4):

You can run Crystal applications on nearly every VPS or container platform with a supported operating system. In the most simplistic case, you build an executable locally (or via CI) and just upload it to your server and execute. Voilá you got yourself a Crystal server.

Answer (score 1):

heroku this tutorial, help you https://crystal-lang.org/2016/05/26/heroku-buildpack.html